Switching to Compiled Tab
I have a project that has number of Variants with many schematic pages. Is there any way to make Altium switch all of the schematic pages to their "compiled Tab" to show the specified project variant that has been currently chosen, in one shot (instead of having to switch each schematic page individually)?
For e.g. as shown below in on of my schematic pages I have the Normal Tab or "Editor" Tab chosen as shown. This displays my "No Variations" options of my schematic page where all the components are displayed

However when I choose the "Compiled Tab" as shown below it displays the components that have been chosen for the specific variant. Those components that are not part of the specific variant have a red cross through them as shown.
To switch to the Compiled tab for each schematic is a bit clumsy and it it would be great if there was some way to make Altium display all the schematic pages already with the compiled tab chosen ( or vice versa).


Can you show an example of what you mean? Are you talking about variants (as in no variations) or Multi-sheet & Hierarchical Designs?
